# One Pack, One Warning

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

**Backstory:**

> In the forest hidden among the trees lies a village full of animals. They live by their animal gods' words. Once every full moon they receive a message from the gods. Occasionally it is a warning hidden among words of mystery. This is one of those cases. The leaders of this animal pack bring these messages to the wise riddlers of the *Stack Exchange Cave.* This message reads these cleverly spun words:
>
> The answer lies within the group
>
> Slowly rattling its brain for a plan
>
> It is a watching, stalking, creeping rat
>
> Is it you? Is it me?
>
> The trick is it treats you like kin
>
> Is it you? Me, you, or him?
>
> The answer lies within, for the right answer is in the group
>
> ---
>
> What is this dire warning? Can you save the pack?

**Hint**- *It doesn't have to be an animal. You could imagine the **pack** was a city, or anything else.*

**Hint2**-*Tags for this puzzle could be* **cryptogram** *and* **poem**

Comment: Is a snake going to kill a rat?

Answer (score 8):

I'm new here and this is a far shot but...

Is it an evil

> gopher

The answer lies within the group

> 'The group' contains the word 'gopher'

Slowly rattling its brain for a plan

> Gophers shake their head around to sense with their whiskers

It is a watching, stalking, creeping rat

> Gophers are rodents, and so are rats

The trick is it treats you like kin

> Gophers look like small and harmless animals but they secretly plan to rule the world

Comment: That's actually a pretty awesome answer, but no xD

Comment: Dammit. I had a feeling it wasn't an animal >_<

Answer (score 2):

By a very long stretch, is the answer

> Roup?

It is

> An infectious disease of poultry and pigeons characterized by inflammation of and mucous discharge from the mouth and eyes.

I believe the backstory is what it was, just a backstory, including the cryptic verse. The only real clue is:

The answer lies within, for the right answer is in the group

> gROUP